# Endless booting loop of MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

My Mac Book Pro 2011 17" recently started to endlessly boot, gets about 2/3s the way into booting then shuts down and starts booting again.
Will not accept the original disks. Will not restart in safe mode? Does this mean I need a new HD or something else?

Comment: It means it's time to do some diagnostics.  Try [Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573_) (Cmd-V) to see what get's output to the console.  You might want to capture it with your camera/smartphone.   Also try [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to verify your hardware.  Hold the "D" key while booting with AC adapter plugged in.  In my experience, this problem ranges from the drive dying to a failure of  almost any component on the logic board.  The key here is to do diagnostics first.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good time to swap the HD for another startup system.
You could do that with a thumb drive startup disk that you or someone else setup already, and you could use a USB cable connected to any external drive that had this. You could probably get one online if you've never made one. You could pull that drive out and connect it to another Mac, then use Disk Utility on it. [Here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/25/how-to-start-up-your-mac-in-internet-recovery-mode/) is an article with some helpful stuff.